# Data Integration between Oracle and External Application?

Tags: c#, oracle, integration, oracle-fusion-middleware

*We have an application that needs certain HR (Human Resource) data like the employee table etc. to initiate the manual and automate workflow process it is used for.*

*Well I am looking into the way to integrate or synchronized with Oracle Data,lets say I get a new customer who has something called "Oracle HR" and they say we will buy your application but we need you to integrate it with our Oracle HR System.*

Our application is in .NET C#.How do I go about integrating with Oracle ?

**1. Are there any web services in oracle
    that expose the data I can poll and
    get and put in my applications
    database?**

**1. Or do I have to ask them to provide
    me a user who can access the data as
    views so that I can connect via
    ADO.NET or any other adapter and get
    the data?**

**2. What the heck is Oracle Fusion
    Middleware in layman developer
    terms? Can it be used or is it hype?**

*Anybody with some experience in this area of two way or one way data integration in an 
enterprise can shed some light?
Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data model is simply enough (HR stuff should be) then I would go with option to connect to Oracle Schema and consume the data.